# Извлечь строку с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка `r`, из которой надо достать только ФИО человека с помощью регулярных выражений. Максимум что у меня вышло это получить '=Иванов Иван Иванович,'.

Как можно дополнить выражение, чтобы получить ФИО без лишних знаков?

```
import re
r = 'CN=Иванов Иван Иванович,OU=0072,OU=007,OU=Users,OU=Departments,DC=contoso,DC=com,DC=ua'
result = re.search(r'=\D+,',r)
print(result)
```

Comment: Из сертификата, что ли вытаскиваете ФИО? :)

Comment: Это из active directory атрибут manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

text = 'CN=Иванов Иван Иванович,OU=0072,OU=007,OU=Users,OU=Departments,DC=contoso,DC=com,DC=ua'

result = re.search(r'CN=(.+?),', text)
print(result)
print(result.group(1))  # 'Иванов Иван Иванович'
```

---

У того текста очень простой формат, можно сгенерировать словарь:

- Поддержка ключей для нескольких значений:

  ```
  from collections import defaultdict
  key_by_values = defaultdict(list)

  for x in text.split(','):
      k, v = x.split('=')
      key_by_values[k].append(v)

  print(key_by_values['CN'])  # ['Иванов Иван Иванович']
  print(key_by_values['OU'])  # ['0072', '007', 'Users', 'Departments']
  ```
- Ключ для одного значения:

  ```
  # В одну строку:
  key_by_value = dict(x.split('=') for x in text.split(','))

  # Или более привычно:
  key_by_value = dict()

  for x in text.split(','):
      k, v = x.split('=')
      key_by_value[k] = v

  print(key_by_value['CN'])  # 'Иванов Иван Иванович'
  print(key_by_value['OU'])  # 'Departments'
  ```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Пока только осваиваю пайтон и регулярки и надо было достать именно ФИО. Все остальные значения в строке не важны.

Comment: @AntonKovbych, понятно, значит ищите пример на котором можно будет тренироваться :)